# question about Limit point of sequence

Tags: real-analysis

May be i am wrong! but i am confused in this. consider the sequence: $$<(-1)^n> = <-1, 1, -1, 1,...>$$
In the text, it is given that 1 and -1 are limit points of sequence $<(-1)^n>$. But we know that a point p is called limit point of sequence $<S_n>$ if for $\epsilon > 0$, $S_n \in (p - \epsilon , p + \epsilon )$ for infinitely many $n \in N$.

But here in above example, clearly we see that if we take 0.5 neighborhood of 1, which is (1-0.5, 1+ 0.5) = (0.5, 1.5) then no points of $<(-1)^n>$ belongs to (0.5, 1.5) except 1 itself! Then how can we say that 1 is limit point of $<(-1)^n>$. please explain me.

Comment: You may find [this discussion of terminology](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/226459/12042) helpful. The main point is that when you’re talking about sequences, you need to distinguish *terms* from *points*. Your sequence hits only two different points, $-1$ and $1$, but it hits each one infinitely often: it has infinitely many *terms* equal to the *point $-1$, and infinitely many terms equal to the point $1$.

Answer (score 1):

When you write  ''Sn ∈ (p - ε , p + ε ) for infinitely many n ∈ N'' this means infinitely many points of the sequence are inside the interval. The number 1 is equal to infinitively points of your sequence, since $$+1=(-1)^{2n},$$ for any n.

Comment: So, 1 itself can be considered as "infinitely many points of <(-1)^n>"  which belongs to any neighbourhood of 1? 
    so from this can we say, all points of sequence, 'which oscillates finitely'  are limit point of that sequence?

Comment: For your first question: YES. But the second not always unless if 'which oscillates finitely' is a misprint and should be 'which oscillates INfinitely on the the same point'

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish two different concepts: the limit of a sequence and limit points of the *range* of a sequence. In fact, the range $\{-1,1\}$ has no limit points, also known as "accumulation points", because as you say, there are no points in small neighborhoods of the points in the range. These are in fact "isolated points" of the range of the sequence. If you now ask what are the limit points of the sequence, these are not usually defined. Usually one only defines "limits" of sequences, and these are unique. So this sequence has no limit, and its range also has no limit points.